# Regarding the ADO Test plans

Tags: azure-devops

I am exploring the ADO service and pretty new to Azure DevOps.

We have a Repo setup where we have two folder in one folder we have a jar file and the other folder we have xml files. We have a pipeline logic ( command prompt step ) to execute the jar file. Once the jar file is executed it will send all the xml files to a JMS queue service. This is working fine.

But we want to leverage the ADO test plans. So, we want to have an attachment in the test case ( XML file which needs to send to JMS queue ). Once the test is execute or run, we are expecting the attachment to commit to Repo. Once the file is committed to Repo then it should trigger the pipeline. So the when the pipeline is executed it will pick the attachment from Repo and send to JMS queue.

Can you help me with this ?